# Can I install an APK on a new Android device before the setup wizard runs?

Tags: apk, side-loading, 8.1-oreo, google-pixel-2, setup-wizard

We got a bunch of Google Pixel 2 (Android 8.1) devices for our employees. We want to install the [Microsoft Intune Company Portal for Android](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49140) app and a LOB application.

To save time, we don't want to go through the setup wizard on every device. But the main requirement is that device should look and feel like new. When the employee turns the device on, he should still be presented the the setup wizard.

The device must not be rooted.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, Android 8.1

Comment: Not 100% sure, but afraid not. To get the APK unto the device, you'll have to turn it on. And to install it e.g. via ADB you'll have to turn on [tag:usb-debugging]. So the next time you turn on the device, it's no longer the first boot and thus the setup wizard won't be started. Only possible way around I can see would be via a custom recovery – which requires to remove the [tag:bootloader-lock].